# How to solve equations self-consistently

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, numerics

I want to solve the following equation self-consistently. So,

```
H.u = e.u

{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} = e.{u1, u2}
```

1. I guess an initial value for `d`
2. Diagonalize `H` and get eigenvectors and eigenfunction `u` and
   `e->Eigenvector[H] Eigenvalue[H]`
3. Define `d ->  d = u1 + u2`
4. Plug `d` in the matrix again
5. Diagonalize `H...` once and again until I get certain convergence,
   i.e., until the value I get for `d` does not change within a certain
   convergence range `dmin`.

Of course, this a really simplified kind of problem of my actual problem I have to solve with a huge matrix.

This is really easy to do in Fortran90, but I wonder how do you do this kind of things in *Mathematica*.

Comment: You can use `FixedPoint`.

Comment: Specifically, `FixedPoint[Total[Eigenvalues[{{1, #}, {#, 1}}]] &, d]` possibly with a `SameTest` setting to account for your `dmin`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `FixedPoint` or possibly `NSolve` or `FindRoot` with one of its methods, if you are willing to specify the values of the non-numeric parameters here.

But be aware that you need to specify the equations to be solved appropriately. First you need `Equal` (`==`, a double equals sign) not `Set` (`=`, single equals sign) to specify your equations. Second you need to set your equations up so that *Mathematica* recognises them as actual equations. Consider:

```
{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} == e.{u1, u2}
```

> ```
> {u1 + d u2, d u1 + u2} == e.{u1, u2}
> ```

This is not a list of equations, and `Dot` doesn't work with a mix of vectors and scalars. Now try the following.

```
Thread[{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} == e {u1, u2}]
```

> ```
> {u1 + d u2 == e u1, d u1 + u2 == e u2}
> ```

```
Solve[Thread[{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} == e {u1, u2}], {u1, u2}]
```

> ```
> {{u1 -> 0, u2 -> 0}}
> ```

```
 Solve[Thread[{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} == e {u1, u2}], {e, d}]
```

> ```
> {{e -> 1, d -> 0}}
> ```

Your real problem is of course bigger than this but it seems to me that if it is linear, you don't necessarily need to iterate to the solution unless you are doing a numerical methods course and you have to complete an assignment that proves it can be done that way.

If you were trying to solve a $m.x=b$ type structure for $x$, then you would use `LinearSolve`.

### Edit to cover FixedPoint

You are right that different disciplines use different terminology to get the same thing. Here is an example using `FixedPointList`, which shows the intermediate iterations for your information. If you don't need these, just use `FixedPoint` with the exact same syntax.

If I understood the list in your question properly, you want the vector `u` to be the eigenvector, but this is a matrix (list of eigenvectors) not a vector. Perhaps you want the first or last ones.

```
FixedPointList[Plus @@ Last@Eigenvectors[{{1, #}, {#, 1}}] &, -0.2, SameTest->delta]
```

To explain this code:

- `Last@Eigenvectors[...]` gives the last eigenvector, which I assume is what you want for `u`. (Maybe `First` instead, it depends on what you're looking for.)
- `Plus @@` takes that list representing `u` and sums it. You could also use `Total`. You did say that the next iteration of `d` was `u1 + u2`.
- Notice the use of `Slot` (`#`) and pure functions to define how `d` is updated.
- The second argument is the starting value for `d`, and the third is the convergence test. Obviously `delta` actually needs to be a small positive number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I indeed need to iterate since what I want to do, is to solve the so called Bogoliubov deGene equations self-consistently(this is related to Superconductivity), so I do need to iterate until d keeps more or less the same. My steps must be: Diagonalization->define d->Diagonalization->redefine d->Diagonalization->redefine d->...until the change in d is smaller than a certain delta. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I'm an economist, so I've no idea what the Bogoliubov deGene equations are. :) But I'll update my answer with a toy example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I indeed need to iterate since what I want to do, is to solve the so called Bogoliubov deGene equations self-consistently(this is related to Superconductivity), so I do need to iterate until d keeps more or less the same. My steps must be: Diagonalization->define d->Diagonalization->redefine d->Diagonalization->redefine d->...until the change in d is smaller than a certain delta. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh! And by the way Verbeia, I am not trying to be rude, but I do not know wether economist know what diagonalization means. It means just to get the eigenvectors(u) and eigenvalues(e) of a matrix(H). I am sure you know it ;). Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, we call it something different. I'm not sure I fully understood what you are trying to do, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: `Thread` is not necessary as `Equal` is automatically threaded over by `Solve`. So, `{{1, d}, {d, 1}}.{u1, u2} == e {u1, u2}` is a perfectly valid set of equations.

Comment: @Mencia if you're going for a spatially inhomogeneous BdG situation you might find [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0568) useful (p. 91, "6.2.2 Numerical methods"). if not inhomogeneous you can just discretise space and solve it numerically (as you're probably doing)

Comment: @Mencia : have you been able to solve the BdG equations using Mathematica ? I have been trying the same and it will be great if you could tell how you have done it.

Comment: @cleanplay , just readed your message, let me know if you still need it.

Comment: @Mencia : thanks for the message. Yes, I still need it. Thanks a lot in advance. :-)

Comment: @cleanplay , what is your mail?